# Swiffy Scroll Display Issue

Tags: google-swiffy

I have a Swiffy ad unit that is essentially showing duplicated (stacked) and is bleeding into a module beneath it. As you scroll past it, the duplicated version goes away.  Attached is a screenshot and the Swiffy ad code. Any idea what I can do to the code to prevent this?

```html
 <style>html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%}</style>
  </head>
<body style="margin: 0; overflow: auto">

    <div id="swiffycontainer_%ecid!" style="width: 300px; height: 250px">
    </div>
    <script>

      var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer_%ecid!'),
          swiffyobject, {});
      stage.setFlashVars("clickTag=%%CLICK_URL_ESC%%%%DEST_URL%%");
      stage.start();
    </script>
  </body>
```

Results in:

[image: ScreenShot of Ad Stacking Issue]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use iframe to contain that swiffy thing

Comment: Thanks Sunny - I will try that now!